# Hibernate criteria with EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="performances")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="id.player", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="player_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="id.season", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="season_id"))
})
public class Performance extends AbstractEntity<PerformanceID> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @Getter @Setter
    private PerformanceID id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private int goals;

    public Player getPlayer(){
        return id.getPlayer();
    }

    public Season getSeason(){
        return id.getSeason();
    }
```

and:

```
@Embeddable
public class PerformanceID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Player.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="player_id")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Player player;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Season.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="season_id")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Season season;
```

How to select Performance records where Players have name 'Claudio' ? In HQL it simply works:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Performance where id.player.name = 'Claudio'");
return query.list();
```

But I need to do it by Criteria API. Following code will fail:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Performance.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("id.player.name", "Claudio"));
return criteria.list();
```

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   id.player.name of:
>   pl.andrzejcichon.criterionlazydatamodel.entities.Performance  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toColumns(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:98)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:61)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1912)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:523)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:538)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.criterion.LikeExpression.toSqlString(LikeExpression.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:419)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.(CriteriaLoader.java:93)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1599)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)   at
>   pl.andrzejcichon.criterionlazydatamodel.repository.impl.PerformanceDatabaseRepository.customList(PerformanceDatabaseRepository.java:29)
>     at
>   pl.andrzejcichon.criterionlazydatamodel.repository.impl.PerformanceDatabaseRepositoryTest.test(PerformanceDatabaseRepositoryTest.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

The other try:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
criteria.createAlias("id.player", "player");
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("player.name", "Claudio"));
return criteria.list();
```

Will generate query:

> Hibernate: select this_.player_id as player2_1_0_, this_.season_id as
>   season3_1_0_, this_.goals as goals1_0_ from performances this_ where
>   player1_.name ilike ?

But it will fail with SQLGrammarException : "Missing FROM clause for table player1_"

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is incorrect. An `EmbeddableId` class should contain `@Id` (thus `Serializable`) values, not mappings or complex types. You should move your mappings to your entity class, and then only include their id's in the `EmbbedableId` class. See the following example (from the JPA 2.2 specification)

```
@Embeddable
public class DependentId {
    String name;
    long empPK;   // corresponds to PK type of Employee
}

@Entity
public class Dependent {
    @EmbeddedId DependentId id;

    // id attribute mapped by join column default
    @MapsId("empPK") // maps empPK attribute of embedded id
    @ManyToOne Employee emp;
}
```

Comment: your example is not compatible with what you are mentioning. I dont see any @Id in the embeddable class, neither it is Serializable

Comment: Only IDE's care about Id's being serializable these days. I was talking about the serializability of the fields. Or more important: they should be basic values. But you could add the interface to the EmbeddedID class as well if you desire ;-) The example actually comes from the JPA spec itself.